# How to hide element, when mouse is out

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want to hide a Div after some time, if the mouse is not over it.
this script is working, but I wonder how it could work better.

```
var i = null;
i = setTimeout(function () {
    $("#info").hide("slow");
}, 7000);
$("#info").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    i = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#info").hide("slow");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with working better? Is there some functionality you are missing? Or do you just want cleaner code?

Comment: Just wanted a cleaner code and I think in mine the timeout wasn't cleared correctly

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this is not exactly what the qeustion is about - just ignore this answer.

You can achieve this without javascript, with pure css:

```
yourDivClass {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
    transition-delay: 2s;
}

yourDivClass:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s ease all;
}
```

Comment: @Rubocop I will take a look on it.

Comment: i want to hide with delay, but not if the mouse is over it.
when mouse is out, then hide with some delay

Comment: But then the element is hidden by default

Comment: @A.Wolff shouldn't it be? Maybe I don't understand the answer correctly.

Comment: the element shouldn't be hidden by default but it should hide with some delay. except the mouse is over it. 
when the mouse leaves it should also hide with some delay

Comment: @Rubocop Oh, I see. I don't think this is possible with pure css then. But MysterX's solution looks pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right. One thing is check if `i` is not `null` before clearing the timeout. And if you want more pretty code, define the timeout callback as the separate function as follows:

```
var i = null;
i = setTimeout(hideInfo, 7000);
$("#info")
  .mousemove(function() {
     if(i){
        clearTimeout(i);
     }
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
     i = setTimeout(hideInfo, 2000);
  });

function hideInfo(){
     $("#info").hide("slow");
}
```

Comment: Checking if `i` is null is useless, since it will only be null between the execution of the first and second lines. Clearing the timeout does not change the value of `i`. Or am I mistaken here?

Comment: You could merge first and second row to `var i = setTimeout(hideInfo, 7000);`

Comment: Changing from `.mousemove` to `.mouseenter` might be a good idea.